# Is it possible to create a generic function to analyze qpcr data in a table in R programming?

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

I have a table whose columns contain the Ct values of the genes and whose rows contain the replicates of each sample. I want to create a function that subtracts the absolute value of individual Cts from the average Cts of the same sample for each column (e gene). Then, if the result of their difference is less than 0.5, the same number of Cts and if it is greater than 0.5, calculate the average Cts of other repetitions of the same sample and enter it in a new column.

My table is like this:

[image]

I have written this code for column c_myc-Ct :

```
##### Filtering data based on |ct-mean ct|<0.5


ct20= ct20%>%  mutate(c_myc_F_mean_Ct=if_else(abs(c(ct20[1:3,1] - mean( ct20[1:3,1]), ct20[4:6,1] - mean( ct20[4:6,1]),ct20[7:9,1] - mean( ct20[7:9,1]),ct20[10:12,1] - mean( ct20[10:12,1]))) <=0.5  ,  c_myc, NA))
```

But I need to write a reproducible function that generally creates new columns by entering specific arguments. Because with every change in my table, the code I wrote will become unusable.

What I expect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~{
     mn <- mean(.x)
     replace(.x, .x > mn, mean(.x[.x <= mn]))
    }, 
    .names = '{sub("Ct","F", .col)}')) %>%
  data.frame()

   Sample C_myc.Ct GAPDH.Ct C_myc.F GAPDH.F
1      S1    38.00    23.70  30.460  23.515
2      S1    30.34    23.56  30.340  23.560
3      S1    30.58    23.47  30.580  23.470
4      S2    30.34    23.65  30.340  23.650
5      S2    30.50    23.69  30.340  23.650
6      S2    30.43    23.68  30.340  23.650
7      S3    27.06    22.76  27.030  22.615
8      S3    27.03    22.61  27.030  22.610
9      S3    27.03    22.62  27.030  22.620
10     S4    27.10    22.60  27.100  22.600
11     S4    26.99    22.61  26.990  22.610
12     S4    40.00    22.76  27.045  22.605
```

Though this becomes tedious to read. So you can break it up as follows:

```
fn <- function(x){
  mn <- mean(x)
  replace(x, x > mn, mean(x[x <= mn]))
}

df %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), fn, .names = '{sub("Ct","F", .col)}')) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Note that the `data.frame` at the end is not necessary. Just wrote it inorder to see that the tibble results do match the expected results

Comment: Dear Onyambu; Thanks for your reply. For me, the 0.5 cut-off is important. Do you confirm the following function? fn <- function(x){
 mn <- mean(x)
 replace(x, abs(x-mn) > 0.5 , mean(x[abs(x-mn) <= 0.5]))
  }